# Trying to populate BootstrapTable with the data from the API

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, axios, react-props, react-functional-component

javascript/react newbie here. I'm trying to populate Table from Bootstrap with the data from the api. I've made two components - Dashboard.js and CustomTable.js, both functional. As far as I got it, on the Dashboard component I need to make API Call - I've done that with useEffect and axios. On the CustomTable.js I need to use useState for columns and data. I want to make my table dynamic, both rows and columns. Take a look at my code for Dashboard.js.

```
 const Dashboard = (props) => {
  let state = [(columns: []), (data: [])];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard-content">
      <Header />
      <NewMessage />
      <CustomTable data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Next, I got my CustomTable.js functional component where I try to pass props from my Parent(Dashboard.js) component, but I'm stuck on where to go next.

```
export default function CustomTable(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(props.columns);

  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {columns.map((row) => {
              return <th>{row.name}</th>;
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((row) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{row.id}</td>
                <td>{row.email}</td>
                <td>{row.first_name}</td>
                <td>{row.last_name}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm sorry if all of this sounds stupid, but I really want to finish this task and continue learning. Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this code ?

Comment: I want to finish my code that will populate table with the data from the api.

Comment: so what's printing right now with your code ?

Comment: Nothing. As I've said I'm lost with what to write next.

Comment: You aren't properly setting the columns and data in dashboard.jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's replace this

```
let state = [(columns: []), (data: [])];
```

with:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ cols: null, data: null });
```

to make your `Dashboard` component look like so:

```
const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ cols: null, data: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`)
      .then((res) => {
        const cols = Object.keys(res.data.data[0]).map((i) => i);
        setData({ data: res.data.data, cols });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard-content">
      {data.data && <CustomTable data={data.data} cols={data.cols} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Your `CustomTable` element doesn't actually even need any state variables, so we can make it look like this:

```
const CustomTable = ({ data, cols }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {cols.map((j, i) => (
              <th key={i}>{j}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((row, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{row.id}</td>
                <td>{row.email}</td>
                <td>{row.first_name}</td>
                <td>{row.last_name}</td>
                <td>{row.avatar}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And that's about all you need. Here is a Sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-architecture-s9dl2?file=/src/App.js